# Show [0,1) could not be countable union of mutually disjoint close interval $[a_n,b_n]$ without using Baire category theorem

Tags: general-topology

This is an exercise 1.2.10 from Terence Tao's book:An introduction to measure theory. Tao hints to use the argument by contradiction and if [0,1) is union of countably many disjoint close intervals then [0,1) could be shown homeomorphic to the middle thirds cantor set! I don't get the idea after thinking for hours. Could any one offer help on this problem?

Comment: I have written part of the solutions here https://math.solverer.com/library/terence_tao/an_introduction_to_measure_theory